# calculator's angle answer for trig ratios that can work in more than 1 quadrant on the unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

1. Why does the calculator do a cc (counterclockwise) rotation for positive trig ratios instead of clockwise,
2. and a clockwise rotation for negative sine & tan instead of cc
3. and a counterclockwise rotation for negative cos ratios instead of a clockwise

ie. *in degree mode*

$\cos^{-1}(-5/12)=114.62$

$\sin^{-1}(-5/12)=-24.62$

$\tan^{-1}(-5/12)=-22.61$

Is it maybe picking the value that involves the least amount of computing power? or is it a matter of convention? or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Conventionally, counter clockwise rotations are described by positive angles. But it looks like your question is more about the ranges of the inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: Try using Mathjax: Surround your formulas with $ signs, use \ before a trig function, and {} between the start and end of a superscript. E.g. \$\cos^{-1}(-5/12)=114.62\$

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This actually has to do with the way inverse trig functions are defined.  For a function to be invertible there must be one input for every output.  Graphically, this is equivalent to passing the *horizontal line test*.  Now, trig functions are periodic and as such are very much not invertible.  The way we get around this is to restrict the domain of each function to a region that passes the horizontal line test.

For $\sin(x)$ the region that we take is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, or $-90^{\circ} \leq x \leq 90^{\circ}$ in degree mode, as seen in the following plot:

[image]

For $\cos(x)$ the region we take is $0\leq x \leq \pi$, or $0^{\circ} \leq x \leq 180^{\circ}$ in degree mode.  Note that we could also have taken $-\pi \leq x \leq 0$, but for convenience we take $x$ to be a positive angle.

[image]

Lastly, for $\tan(x)$ we can take a full period around the origin, so $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, or $-90^{\circ} \leq x \leq 90^{\circ}$ in degree mode.

[image]

Comment: That makes complete sense!  When you see the graph of the functions, sure enough they give out the reasons why the calculators give out the answers they do.